# Android Layout with 3 Sections

Tags: java, android

I am working on a basic Android app that has 3 "sections" in the layout for the main activity ->

1. Ad banner at the top
2. Main section for content
3. BottomNavigationView at the bottom

The layout I have works, but the ad banner at the top overlaps some of the main section (Note: the ad banner is dynamically created and inserted into `ad_layout` with `match_parent` width and `wrap_content` height). I want the ad banner to occupy its own space and then have the main section occupy its own space and then the BottomNavigationView occupy its own space.

The XML I have right now seems like a mess. Is there a better way to have 3 distinct sections, each occupying their own space? Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/outer_layout">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
    <!-- Main Content -->
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/primary_dark"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/toolbar_bottom_menu"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/outer_layout">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/main_layout"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ad_layout"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar_bottom"/>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/primary_dark"
            app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
            app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:menu="@menu/toolbar_bottom_menu"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Is CoordinatorLayout still needed with these changes? Also I think I need to use the androidx version of ConstraintLayout.

Comment: You can use a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout` if you want to, but you can't use a `FrameLayout` or the content will be overlapped

Comment: `CoordinatorLayout` is only needed if you want some custom interaction between views. I think that you can safely remove it in this case

Comment: I removed `CoordinatorLayout` and the rest of the proposed solution works for me. Thanks